# Importar HTML Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Estou usando o `nodemailer` para envio de emails no meu servidor node, porem, não gostei de armazenar todo o `HTML` em uma variavel, gostaria de saber se é possivel eu deixar salvo em um `arquivo.html` e apenas chamar o conteúdo dele para enviar esse email. Atualmente estou usando dessa maneira.

```
conta.sendMail({
                    from: 'meuemail@gmail.com',
                    to: req.body.nome+' <'+req.body.email+'>',
                    subject: 'ASSUNTO',
                    html: html
                }, (err) => {
                    if(err){
                        throw err
                    }else{
                        console.log('Email Enviado')
                    }
                })
```

a variavel `html` esta sendo declarado com todo o `html`que irei enviar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer com HTML, utilizando o email-templates https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates.

Segue um modelo de exemplo:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var EmailTemplate = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate;
var welcome = new EmailTemplate(templateDir);
var path = require('path'); 
var templateDir = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'templates', 'welcome'); 


var defaultTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'hotmail',  
 auth: {
    user: teste@email.com,
    pass: 1234   
}});

module.exports = {

    boasVindas: function(user){
        welcome.render(user, function (err, result) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                var transport = defaultTransport;
                transport.sendMail({
                    from: "email@gmail.com",
                    to: user.email,
                    subject: "Bem vindo",
                    html: result.html
                }, function (err, responseStatus) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(responseStatus) // email foi enviado
                    }                    
                });
            }            
        });
    },

}
```

No exemplo acima, o caminho do arquivo está em /templates/welcome, e dentro desta pasta tem um arquivo **html**.html.